# Java CGlib Enhancer for Selective class or method

Tags: java, spring, cglib

I would like to develop an utiity class to intercept few methods of my project. Currently my project has 120+ java files and I would like to intercept say 15 methods in 10 files. How to achieve that using Cglib enhancer?

Also lets say I have following code

```
class A{
 B b = new B();
 C c = new C():
 void m1(){
   b.m2();
   c.m3();
 }
}
```

I would like to intercept only method m1() and m3(). Is it possible, if yes how to do that?

Comment: You can mark your methods with a custom runtime annotation for example @InterceptAround, create proxies with MethodInterceptor callback (using Enhancer), then on java.lang.reflect.Method you can try to retrieve custom annotation, if it founds, do something, else - skip. More convienent way is to use Spring AOP. You can create Aspect and activate it on specific JoinPoints like annotations, method signatures, packages and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cglib works by creating subclasses for your types at runtime. Therefore, what you suggest is not possible using cglib. For your class `A`, cglib's `Enhancer` creates a class similar to:

```
class A$Proxy extends A {

  MethodInterceptor interceptor;

  @Override
  void m1(){
    interceptor.intercept("m1");  
  }
}
```

This way, cglib can call your code instead of the original implementation. However, the field instances of the `A` class are not virtual and cannot be modified by cglib due to the subclassing approach. With cglib, no existing code is actually changed.

Instead, you should look into using Java agents which allow you to redefine existing code what allows for the AOP programming style that you are looking for. There are libraries more powerful than cglib like for example [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy), a library that I wrote. I once wrote down an example for such AOP with Byte Buddy on the example of logging if you are interested: http://mydailyjava.blogspot.no/2015/01/make-agents-not-frameworks.html